# Desktop background image from a website?

Tags: windows-7, automation, desktop, desktop-customization

Is it possible that desktop background image automatically comes from a website?

For example, I want to have my desktop image from http://xkcd.com/ homepage?

There is a [discussion](http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=3095) on how to get the latest image, but don't know how that could be applied to this post.